# Facebook Connect Redirecting

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Connect plugin for MyBB.  Right now it always goes back to the index of the forum.  I'd like it to go to the last page a person visited instead.  Anytime I try putting in variables it ends up giving a server configuration error.

Relevant code:

```
$fbconnectjavascript = "<script type="text/javascript">
                `<!--`
                `window.location = "../index.php"`
                `//-->`
                `</script>`";
```

Comment: Please show us more then just one line of code; we really need to see the whole thing.